# How can I make a Stacked Column graph of this data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, csv

I have a CSV file that was output from a program and I am trying to create a Stacked Column graph in Excel of the data, but the default suggested graphs have the data interpreted wrong and on the wrong axis. Flipping the X and Y axis doesn't help either, so I'm wondering whether the way I'm trying to insert the chart is messed up or if the way my data is on the spreadsheet is bad. Cell A1 and B1 are the labels: Data and Time (seconds) respectively. The data spans as follows:

```
Date        Time

20150401    6

20150401    6

20150401    20

20150401    99

20150401    20

20150402    99

20150402    5

20150402    21

20150402    19

20150402    0

20150402    21

20150406    14

20150406    0
```

Note that column A is in the YYYYMMDD format and the column B is always just a whole integer, but sometimes the same date has multiple readings, so I would like to stack those when that happens.

Can it be done? Is there a better way to format my data to be more Excel friendly? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot how your chart looks like? And explain what exactly is wrong with it? Excel won't understand yyyymmdd format as date, you need to properly format it before you can make the chart. What do you mean by stack them? Sum, average, different colour for each row...?

Comment: A stacked chart stacks "series" of data.  You don't have anything separating your values that share the same date into individual series, so Excel doesn't know how to stack them.  So, if you want a stacked column you'll need to introduce a series value somehow.  If you're simply looking to total the values by date, then that's a slightly different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this quickly using a Pivot Table and Pivot Chart.

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table (Excel likes your data in tables).
2. Using your data Table, create a Pivot Table.  This will automatically subtotal your time values by date.  Format your pivot table with:
   Row labels = Date
   Values = Time
3. Create an appropriate Pivot Chart type (e.g. I prefer Bar to Column) from your Pivot Table and format to taste.

[image]

If you really want a Stacked Chart, you'll need to add a series to your data.  The series can be completely arbitrary (like my example), or another attribute in your data that you add to your table.  That attribute is then becomes Excel's characteristic for determining each series, but the result (sum of Time by Date) is the same.

[image]